# Minify and Concatenate Javascript files without Grunt/Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, minify

I have 50+ JavaScript files that I'd like to concatenate and minify with the goal of reducing file size and HTTP requests. However, I am doing it for a client project that does not have Node or npm installed. What is the best way to achieve this goal without installing Node/npm? Also, is it possible use Grunt/Gulp without using npm for the project?

Answer (score 0):

Use online javascript minification tools like [JsCompress](http://jscompress.com/) or other alike services. You have to select files, compress and download single file